# How do I get windows login id from a php script?

Tags: php, apache

I have a PHP web application. When a user opens it I need to get the log in id of the windows system. I don't authenticate the user again.

I heard of Active Directory, but I don't want to authenticate the user again. When my web application is opened the username should be captured automatically.

How can I get the log in id in my PHP script?

I also heard of configuring Apache server for mod_ntlm environment and REMOTE_USER variable etc. I don't know all those. Can any one put it very simply so that I can go ahead and configure all those?

Comment: How do you know the user is browsing there from Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if running on an internal LAN only and all the windows machines on the network authenticate against either an SBS or Full blown windows Active Directory you can query the login of the user browsing the page with an LDAP query.  I did this years and years ago for an intranet.  Its pretty reliable but only works for internal users authenticated against the windows domain.

**BASIC LDAP QUERY**

```
    <?php

    // basic sequence with LDAP is connect, bind, search, interpret search result,
    // close connection

    $ds=ldap_connect("192.168.0.1");        // ! Your LDAP/Active Direcotry Server !
    echo "Connection: ".$ds."";

    if ($ds) {
            echo "Binding ..";
            $r=ldap_bind($ds);        // this is an "anonymous" bind, typically read-only access
            echo "Bind result is ".$r."";
            echo "Searching for (sn=A*) .."; // this example searches surname entry for all surnames starting with A
            $sr=ldap_search($ds,"o=Organisation Name, c=UK", "sn=A*"); // ! must use real base dn here !
            echo "Search result is ".$sr."";
            echo "Number of entires returned is ".ldap_count_entries($ds,$sr)."";
            echo "Getting entries ...";
            $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
            echo "Data for ".$info["count"]." items returned:";

            for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {
               echo "dn is: ". $info[$i]["dn"] ."";
               echo "first cn entry is: ". $info[$i]["cn"][0] ."";
               echo "first email entry is: ". $info[$i]["mail"][0] ."";
            }
    //now  close connection
    ldap_close($ds);
} else {
    echo "Unable to connect to LDAP server";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt very much if any web application can get the windows login id - that would be a pretty severe security problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, the best you can do is store the user's ip and use that to automatically log them in (after they've authenticated once).  You can obtain the user's ip from $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].

Keep in mind though, IPs can be spoofed and can change (sometimes frequently, sometimes rarely), so it's not a very secure or reliable way to log someone in automatically.  However, depending on the nature of your application, it could be sufficient.  Particularly if you're only using it on an intranet (in which case you could set static ips, if needed).